# Save form data to google spreadsheet PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets

I have Form Like this. I wanted to Save this form Data in my Google Drive (Google Spreadsheet) using **Core Php**

```
<div class="form">
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="signup">
         <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
         <form action="/" method="post">
            <div class="top-row">
               <div class="field-wrap">
                  <label>
                  First Name<span class="req">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
               </div>
               <div class="field-wrap">
                  <label>
                  Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field-wrap">
               <label>
               Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
               </label>
               <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Submit</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- tab-content -->
</div>
<!-- /form -->
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below link

http://farinspace.com/2009/05/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/

and it is worked for me

Comment: This solution is too old to be accepted. Does google not support this officially?

Comment: Outdated, check here: https://www.nidup.io/blog/manipulate-google-sheets-in-php-with-api